# SocketIO namespace rooms and except

Tags: socket.io

In socketio 0.9 namespace had an **except** method

https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/0.9.14/lib/namespace.js#L122

```
/**
 * Adds a session id we should prevent relaying messages to (flag).
 *
 * @api public
 */

SocketNamespace.prototype.except = function (id) {
  this.flags.exceptions.push(id);
  return this;
};
```

In 1.0 this **except** disappeared.

https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/blob/master/lib/namespace.js

What worked before:

```
io.of('/foo').in(room).except(sockeId).emit(event, data);
```

Does not work anymore, except is **unknown**.

This fails at well:

```
io.of('/foo').broadcast.to(room).emit(event, data);
//'TypeError: Cannot call method \'to\' of undefined',
```

I could not find flags.exception in 1.0, is there anyway to broadcast from a namespace??

Comment: For now I forked socketio to add except to namespace... but maybe I am using it wrong.